# PHP: Global variable for all pages

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

I need a constant that can be called from every php page.
So, for example, I declare this constant somewhere, `$APP_VERSION = "5.5"`.

Then I would like to call this variable from any pages. how to do this?

Comment: constants **are not** variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('APP_VERSION', '5.5');
```

You can put that in the file that would be included into your pages. I'n that way you'd access it by `APP_VERSION`

```
echo APP_VERSION; //outputs 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a file (for example costant.php) which will contains all your constants and then you have to use `include` to be able to retrieve them in every script.

Comment: You don't 'have' to do any such thing. Although you may if you want to of course.

Comment: @vascowhite I really don't understand the downvote. My answer is not wrong and of course is one of the one thousand method that works. But really I see no reason to downvote. Anyway it's your right to do.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa While its not 'wrong', its not really 'right' either. You imply a file called `costant.php` is *required* to make global constants, which is simply false.

Comment: @phindmarsh I wanted to do an example, not to force that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can define constants using `define`:

```
define('APP_VERSION', '5.5');
```

Then, in other files:

```
echo APP_VERSION; // outputs '5.5'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php